# The event is not firing. Couldn't find the reason

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-reactive-forms

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[sdScrollBottom]"
})
export class ScrollBottomDirective {
  @Output() onUserScroll: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef
  ) {
  }

  @HostListener("touchmove", ["$event"])
  @HostListener("scroll", ["$event"]) onStart(event) {
    this.onUserScroll.emit(event);
  }
}
```

> This is the code of a custom directive. The event is not firing.

Comment: Try "window:scroll" see if works

Comment: `scroll` does not bubble. You can only listen to it directly on the element being scrolled.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this,

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Directive({
    selector: '[scrollBottom]'
})
export class ScrollBottomDirective
{
    @Output() scrollEnd:EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

    scrl_top:string;
    client_height:string;
    scrl_height:string;

    constructor(
        public el: ElementRef
    )
    {}

    @HostListener('scroll')
    scroll()
    {
        this.scrl_top = this.el.nativeElement.scrollTop;
        this.client_height = this.el.nativeElement.clientHeight;
        this.scrl_height = this.el.nativeElement.scrollHeight;

        // console.log('s top ', this.scrl_top, ' client height ', this.client_height, ' scrl - height ', this.scrl_height)
        if((this.scrl_top+this.client_height) === this.scrl_height)
        {
            if(this.scrollEnd) {
                this.scrollEnd.emit(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any such issue that @Output is not supported below angular 5.2.6